# no me funciona el menu avanzado en batch

Tags: batch, menu

cree un pequeño menu y me gustaria ponerles una linea. Encontre una forma

> Es el siguiente en pantalla

```
echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo º #Opciones:       º
echo º                  º
echo º  1.Ayuda         º
echo º  2.Salir         º
echo º                  º
echo ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
```

pero Entro y me Lanza unos Simbolos extraños. Entre como administrador y no funciono tampoco. ¿como Puedo Hacer que no me salgan esos simbolos y salgan lineas?

Answer (score 0):

Los .bat no admiten letras con acentos, para que no te salgan los símbolos extraños tienes que cambiarlo por letras sin acento.

Comment: En realidad no es que los archivos `.bat` no acepten acentos. Todo recae más bien en tipo de "codificación" que utilizan `CMD.exe` o `PowerShell`. Como verás en [esta pregunta en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line/388500#388500) existen alternativas para solucionar el problema, pero ojo, que tienen que usarse bajo propio riesgo.

Comment: pero me descarge un archivo batch y en las letras con acentos salian unas lineas

Comment: Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo en el cmd, este no podrá leer letras con acentos y otros caracteres extraños